# How to get Max column with group by using MS SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

What I want to query is "get user's last fatal logs". When I query below statement it only returns "username" and "logDate" fields but I also want to get this "logDate"'s corresponding row(I mean logid, logdata);

```
SELECT user.username, MAX(log.logDate) FROM user 
INNER JOIN log ON user.userid = log.userid
WHERE log.logtype = 'fatal'
GROUP BY user.username
```

My user table;

```
userid  username   
-----------------
1       robert
2       ronaldo
```

log table;

```
logid  logDate                    logtype  userid  logdata
----------------------------------------------------------
1      2016-11-28 19:37:53.000    fatal    1       data
2      2016-11-28 22:37:53.000    fatal    1       data
3      2016-11-28 12:37:53.000    fatal    2       data
```

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will do this using `CROSS APPLY`(preferred approach with proper index added to `Log` table)

```
SELECT *
FROM   [USER] u
       CROSS apply (SELECT TOP 1 *
                    FROM   log l
                    WHERE  u.userid = l.userid
                           AND l.logtype = 'fatal'
                    ORDER  BY l.logDate DESC) cs
```

If the `log` table is very large then create a `Non Clustered Index` on Log table to improve the performance

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX NIX_Log_logtype_userid
ON [log] (logtype,userid)
INCLUDE (logid,logDate,logdata)
```

---

Another approach using `ROW_NUMBER`

```
SELECT *
FROM   (SELECT *,
               Row_number()OVER(partition BY [USER].username ORDER BY log.logDate DESC) AS rn
        FROM   [USER]
               INNER JOIN log
                       ON [USER].userid = log.userid
        WHERE  log.logtype = 'fatal') A
WHERE  rn = 1
```

Another approach using `ROW_NUMBER` and `TOP 1 with ties`

```
SELECT TOP 1 WITH ties *
FROM   [USER]
       INNER JOIN log
               ON [USER].userid = log.userid
WHERE  log.logtype = 'fatal'
ORDER  BY Row_number()OVER(partition BY [USER].username ORDER BY log.logDate DESC)
```

**Note :** All the queries result all the column from both the tables select the required columns

Answer (score 2):

A quick option would be to get the max logdate in a subquery. This way, you can select any fields you need from the user table and don't have to aggregate in the outer query. The only issue with this one is that your logdate needs to not have duplicates. If it's a datetime then this isn't likely but you may have duplicates if it's just a date field. Worth checking.

```
SELECT
     u.username
    ,u.logdate
    ,u.logid
    ,u.logdata
FROM user u
INNER JOIN (SELECT 
                userid
                ,MAX(logdate) MaxLog 
            FROM log 
            WHERE logtype = 'fatal' 
            GROUP BY userid) l
    ON u.userid = l.userid
    AND u.logdate = l.MaxLog
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [**`ROW_NUMBER`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) for this:

```
SELECT user.username, 
       log.logid, log.logtype, log.logDate, log.logdata
FROM (
   SELECT user.username, 
          log.logid, log.logtype, log.logDate, log.logdata,
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY user.username 
                             ORDER BY log.logDate DESC) AS rn
   FROM user 
   INNER JOIN log ON user.userid = log.userid
   WHERE log.logtype = 'fatal') AS t
WHERE t.rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH MaxLogDate AS (
    SELECT user.userid, MAX(log.logDate) logDate FROM user 
    INNER JOIN log ON user.userid = log.userid
    WHERE log.logtype = 'fatal'
    GROUP BY user.userid
)
SELECT log.logid, log.logDate, log.logtype, u.userid, u.username
FROM user u
    JOIN MaxLogDate m ON u.userid = m.userid  
    JOIN log ON log.logDate = m.logDate AND log.userid = m.userid 
WHERE log.logtype = 'fatal' --This line is optional, may increase the performance.
```